# Flicker in nav bar styling when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a flickering issue with my bottom-border (nav link) when I scroll within a certain section. I suppose it's not really a flicker, but a transition that's being resetted every time I scroll within that section. For example (refer to source below), if my window is currently in a section and I scroll little by little, the border-bottom of my active nav link will flicker. In addition, if I hold onto the scroll bar and scroll down, the border-bottom disappears.

I'd like for it to:
1) Not flicker when scrolling.
2) When scrolling on the page with the scroll bar, keep the border-bottom present.

http://jsfiddle.net/binhxn89/zzmbex55/16/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="container cf">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#welcome" class="link active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link1" class="link">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2" class="link">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link3" class="link">link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link4" class="link">link4</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="welcome" class="welcome"></section>
<section id="link1" class="link1"></section>
<section id="link2" class="link2"></section>
<section id="link3" class="link3"></section>
<section id="link4" class="link4"></section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

    .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
}
.navbar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover,
.navbar ul li a.active {
    margin-top: -3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

section {
    height:100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

.welcome {
    background: #ebebeb;
}

.link1 {
    background: #aaa;
}
.link2 {
    background: #bbb;
}
.link3 {
    background: #ccc;
}
.link4 {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function () {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.link').each(function (event) {
      if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 10) {
        $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 600);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
})
```

If anyone could help or refer me to a particular source regarding this issue, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Tested in Chrome and Firefox, present in both. Also, observation; if you let the animation finish, this issue doesn't appear.

Comment: @Scriptable I'm using Chromium, but I guess I'd like for it to work for every browser.

Comment: @TimLewis Would you happen to have an idea of how to ignore or bypass the finishing animation issue?

Comment: I'm still looking at it... Haven't had any luck yet. And don't worry too much about the browser thing. First comment was likely asked to see if it was only a certain browser that had the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzmbex55/20/) or take a look at the code below. First, I calculate the heigh of one element and get his position. After that I compare the part to the current position. So far, no flickering on Safari or Chrome, I hope this will fix it. It seams that your solution raised multiple events, if you look at the `console.log(y);` you will notice a lot of double values for part 2, 3, 4 and 5.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sectionHeigth = $('section').height();
    var part = Math.round((y / sectionHeigth));

    $('.link').each(function(event) {
        var position = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
        if ((part * sectionHeigth) != position) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/zzmbex55/26/) to your comment. I'll check if the current position is between the `start` and `start + height` position. That's all.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.link').each(function(event) {
        var position = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
        var a = $($(this).attr('href')).height();
        if (y >= position && y <= position + a) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I guess I should have been more specific, but the answer did solve that specific issue, so thank you! 
However, I was wondering if you knew how to solve the issue if the section height was not specified at all. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/binhxn89/zzmbex55/24/ , these nav links aren't functioning as mentioned above. Please let  me know if you can fix this one!

Comment: @binhxn89 Please have a look at my update. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response, it works! I've been working on a one page website and began to add some content to each section that takes up about a window height. In addition to your last updated answer, I was wondering how to make the nav link change when the next section is halfway (or 3/4 of the way) scrolled up from the window view/height? Hopefully this is the last thing I will ask. You've been extremely helpful!

Comment: @binhxn89 Just adapt the range in the if clause `(y >= position && y <= position + a)`. Or move the start position to a earlier position. `y` is the current position. `position` is the section position and `a` the heigh of the section. I hope that helps.